# fail gradle build if transitive dependency is used directly?

Tags: java, gradle

im looking for a way to fail my gradle build if my code directly uses (so imports) a transitive dependency.

what i mean is if my project has a (compile) dependency on module A, and module A depends on B (so B is in my transitive dependencies and available on my runtime classpath) and my code directly imports and uses classes from B, i want my build to fail.

here's a maven plugin that does what i want - https://github.com/Scout24/illegal-transitive-dependency-check - but i cant find a gradle one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 2 plugins below may be what you're looking for.

1. https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze

   From the [README](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze):

   > This plugin attempts to replicate the functionality of the maven dependency plugin's analyze goals which fail the build if dependencies are declared but not used or used but not declared.
2. https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin

   On the [Unused Dependency Rule](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule) wiki page:

   > 2. Promotes transitive dependencies that are used directly by your code to explicit first order dependencies

I have to say I haven't used either one myself, but they seem to address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use the [java library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) and the api/implementation configurations.

For the legacy java plugin you could do

```
dependencies {
   compile('group:module-b:1.0') { transitive = false }
}
```

This would force you to explicitly declare module-b's transitive dependencies if you need to use them.

Note: You'll probably get lots of ClassNotFoundException using module-b at runtime since there's now jars missing from your classpath. So this might be better

```
dependencies {
   compile('group:module-b:1.0') { transitive = false }
   runtime 'group:module-b:1.0'
}
```

Comment: not what im looking for - i still need those transitives at runtime (and i dont want to keep chasing after what they are as i update to newer versions of A).

i just want to keep developers honest - anything you use you should have a DIRECT dependency on

Comment: Look at my second suggestion, theyll be available at runtime. But developers on your source will be "kept honest" as they won't be able to compile without direct dependencies

Comment: true, but they'd need to list all their dependencies twice, which is weird and error-prone.